# What is the most efficient way I can to get a list of locations sorted by proximity given a location?

Tags: algorithm, geolocation, gps

For example,

Say I have a database of locations (latitude/longtitude), and a point. How can I grab the top 25 nearest locations from the database of locations?

Is there too a library, or a resource I can read up on various geospatial operations like above? Thanks!

Comment: bonus: is there a way to find out various info (state, country) given its lang/long?

Comment: The answer depends on your database - you should use a spatial indexing module for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do sounds like a [nearest neighbour search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).

[K-d trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) are an efficient data structure to achieve this.

The [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) library has [spatial searching](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Spatial_searching/Chapter_main.html) functions if you're looking for a library for C++.

Comment: what about http://code.google.com/p/python-kdtree/ or http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/KDTree ?